# How to filter webpart for multiple values

Tags: 2010, web-part, filter

I've added a list webpart (using UI) to a webpage and also added a Choice Filter Webpart. It appears I can only filter the list using a single value, i.e. multi-values are not supported.

Is there any other easy options, perhaps :

1. SPD options
2. JavaScript options

I've tried changing the view but the page redirects off the Site page onto the list, something I don't want. The user must remain on the site page. The list webpart also has connections to other webparts.

Any help welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Query String and multiple values filters and CSOM for create the choice filter.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24702889/sharepoint-filtering-list-with-multiple-values-of-the-same-field

http://sharepointificate.blogspot.com.ar/2012/12/filtering-listviews-with-url-query.html

Answer (score 1):

I created a calculated column. The formula checked for the differing states of status and gave only two outputs, incomplete and complete. Then used the calculated column in the Filter Choice. This worked for me but will have limited usage.